# NameError: name 'AnsibleModule' is not defined in PyCharm

Tags: python, ansible, pycharm

I am having a python script along with ansible modules integrated. While executing in PyCharm, getting AnsibleModule not defined and it is not recognizing any ansible keywords. Any idea? Do I need to install any additional plugins for PyCharm to execute ansible based Python scripts? Here is my code

```
def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec = dict(
        hostvars = dict(required=True, type='dict'),
        topology = dict(required=True, type='list'),
        my_hostname = dict(required=True)
    )
)
try:
    hostvars = module.params['hostvars']
    topology = module.params['topology']
    my_hostname = module.params['my_hostname']
    facts = get_facts(hostvars, topology, my_hostname)
    module.exit_json(changed=False, ansible_facts=facts)
except Exception as error:
    module.fail_json(msg=str(error))
```

Thanks,
Sridhar A

Comment: are you using pip or anaconda? do you have Ansible downloaded?

Comment: How have you imported / referenced it? Please show you problematic code.

Comment: I have ansible installed and above is the code

Comment: Did you import it in the script? do you have it installed for the same version of python you are running in pycharm?

Comment: Thats what my question is. How to import ansible in to Pycharm?

Comment: before your function you must use import Ansible

Comment: Below is the error i am getting while i am importing ansible 

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansible'

Comment: @moderators:  this is an IDE related question, and there are several IDE questions about pycharm in stackoverflow.  I would vote to keep this open.  Several members of my team have asked variations of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your [project interpreter in pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html).  IIRC, this may be a feature only available in pycharm pro.  You should point the interpreter at your virtualenv and that will get you up and  moving.